# Postgresql check if exists vs unique constraint in table

Tags: postgresql

Am inserting huge number of records containing Phone Number and Status (a million) in a postgresql database from hibernate. I am reading the records from a file, processing each, and inserting them one at a time. But before the insert I need to check whether this combination of phone number and status already exists in the table.

It seems to me that the fastest way would be to do a query and limit it by 1, or an Exists query, but another suggestion I got from a colleague is to add a unique constraint on the table on the phone number and status fields and in case the unique key rule is being violated, just catch the exception in hibernate.

Any thoughts on what's the fastest and most reliable method?

Comment: Do both. An `exists` query and the unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether there are only these columns, or also some others, for example date. If you don't care which record will stay in database (for example you need latest combination of number, status and date), then create unique constraint and recover from exception that is thrown when inserting duplicities.

You may also insert all with duplicities but with some primary key (id) and then delete all duplicities but one you like to have (group by...), then create unique constraint.

Last option depends on size of records - if it is only 1M of them, you may filter them in application layer and then save them.

All of these depend on how much duplicities are there, if just few, use option one, if each record may be there 10 times, maybe last option is the best (depending on RAM, but you will hold only currently best record for phone and status)